# Enabling SQL Ad Hoc Distributed Queries for a single command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to read data from Excel files to make hundreds of updates to SQL Server. The server is by default configured to not allow these queries, but I can change this setting. I read about the risks of allowing these queries, but I was wondering if there are security concerns or performance issues or other risks I don't know about, if I enable them for the duration of a single command.

In short, is it reasonable to do the following?

```
exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
reconfigure

begin try

    select * from OPENROWSET(

    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'

    ,'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Temp\Test.xlsx;'

    ,'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') as xl
end try

begin catch
    print 'Error occurred'
end catch

exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',0
reconfigure
```

I would of course wrap this in a stored procedure and use it many times over for different source and target tables.

Comment: Not answering the question, but I found a simpler route, namely creating a csv file from Excel, and using BULK INSERT into temp table. No need to fiddle with server settings.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question based on my own findings, the answer is no, the above is not quite reasonable.

Apparently the GO keyword is necessary at least after the reconfigure statements. I couldn't get a successful test as the server machine did not have the ACE OleDb provider installed.

Also, try-catch does not catch errors relating to the missing provider. So if someone can tell how this could be done safely, please do.